# Datetime triggers in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

Here is an example of the problem:

`datetime.utcnow()` is currently: `2015-02-18 22:31:00`

There is way to make Python call a method or execute any action when `datetime.utcnow()` reaches `2015-02-18 22:35:00` ? I wanna do this without a loop to check if `datetime.utcnow()` reached `2015-02-18 22:35:00`, just like a trigger.

Any suggestions?

thanks,

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this asynchronously, you can use [threading.Timer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects):

```
t = threading.Timer(secondsUntilDesiredTime, myFunction)
t.start()
```

However, the timer is not guaranteed to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cronjob from python with the python-crontab module: [python-crontab 1.9.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab)

That way you can trigger an action at that specific time.